# List View item is not gettting wrap content height using `ArrayAdapter`

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-arrayadapter

`ListView` item is not getting wrap content height as I need to show only
I tried to set dynamic height to item but it's not working.
Please provide other solutions.

String in it's item. I am using `ArrayAdapter` and here is the code of `TextView` that I am using for inflating the item.
Thank you

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:ellipsize="none"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp2"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp2"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

I am trying to set ListView's items height using below code -

```
 for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {
            View item = arrayAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, listView);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            item.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            item.measure(item.getMeasuredWidth(), item.getMeasuredHeight());
            totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
```

Comment: Please post screen shot

Comment: can  you post a screenshot of your screen ?

Comment: Could you share your screen and explain what is not working as @HirenPatel bhai said.

Comment: if your problem is to make sure the textview contains multilines, you have that property maxlines  , and singleLine=false to work it out.  You shouldn't need to set the height by yourself

Comment: @Ghanshyan textview width is not "match_parent" use "wrap_content"

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

on your TextView cell layout. Should change the TextView height dinamically based on their content.

Delete this two lines:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
item.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

And do you have your for code onCreate() or onStart()? because if it's onCreate it's probably that getMeasuredHeigh() returns 0 always.

Comment: Yes, I tried with "wrap_content"
But it's not working for me.

Comment: Put wrap_content on your TextView anyway, but if it's not working you have another problem in another place. Maybe in the code? in the ListView layout? Tell us more.

Comment: I am not struggling with ListView height.
I need to provide ListView items height wrap_content.
Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change as below:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp2"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: Yes, I tried with "wrap_content" But it's not working for me

Comment: Can you please add screenshot?

Comment: Dhruv,
Each ListView  item(textView) is scrolling in itself if the String size is more than one.
Each item is showing 1 line String at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give some hardcoded value and check if it works instead of wrap content or just rebuild the project and try again with wrap_content

Comment: By hardcoaded, Its not getting perfect height, Some time String is 2 lines and some time its 5 line.
So It's not a good solution to make it hardcoded

Comment: Did you trying cleaning or rebuilding the project ?